# Is there any reason not to use the shopkeepers from my Tavern?

Tags: soda-dungeon

Pretty early on you unlock the ability to bring your shopkeepers along on your dungeon exploits. These blokes have some powerful abilities and high stats... is there any reason for me take the generic classes over them? In particular, the Wizard seems like a more powerful conjurer.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some basic science I have a preliminary answer.

The reason not to use them is that these shopkeepers become available for unlock significantly before you'll be earning the in-game currency it actually takes to unlock them. They're available for purchase with real money, though.

I will update this answer when I can actually test out using them.